# Common solution to two equations as a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question about an exercise I am working on for a linear algebra class. The exercise is as follows

> Let $\vec{v}_1=(1,1,1,1)$ and $\vec{v}_2=(3,5,2,1)$, and let $V$ be the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ spanned by $\vec{v}_1$ and $\vec{v}_2$. Find two equations, each of the form $ax+by+cz+dw=0$, such that the common solution to these equations is the subspace $V$.

So, if $\vec{v}_1=(1,1,1,1)$ and $\vec{v}_2=(3,5,2,1)$ span $V$, then every vector in $V$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $\vec{v}_1=(1,1,1,1)$ and $\vec{v}_2=(3,5,2,1)$. That is, for any two scalars $c$ and $d$,

$$c\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
1\\ 
1\\ 
1\\
\end{bmatrix}
+
d\begin{bmatrix}
3\\ 
5\\ 
2\\ 
1\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\ 
y\\ 
z\\ 
w\\
\end{bmatrix}
.$$

From here I use an augmented matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}
 1&  3|& x\\ 
 1&  5|& y\\ 
 1&  2|& z\\ 
 1&  1|& w
\end{bmatrix}$$

which, after putting into RREF form, yields

$$\begin{bmatrix}
 1&  0|& 2w-z\\ 
 0&  1|& z-w\\ 
 0&  0|& x-3w-2z\\ 
 0&  0|& y-5w-4z
\end{bmatrix}$$

Does this give me the two equations I am asked to provide? It would be

$$x-3w-2z=0$$
$$y-5w-4z=0$$

Comment: I'm not sure you computed the RREF correctly ($z=w=1$, $x=5$, and $y=9$ satisfy the two equations. This gives $d=0$ and $c=1$; but $cv_1+dv_2\ne[5,9,1,1]$). But your general method is sound. Redo the RREF...

Comment: You know you can't be right because $x-3w-2z=-4$ when you plug in $(x,y,z,w)=(1,1,1,1)=v_1$.

Comment: I computed as an echelon form (note, you need not do the "backwards reduction") as: $$\left[\matrix{ 1&3\cr 0&2\cr 0&0\cr0&0} \ \ \ \left|\ \ \matrix{x\cr y-x\cr-3x+2z+y\cr 2x-w-y} \right.\right]$$

Answer (score 1):

You may simply find two nontrivial solutions $(a,b,c,d)$ to the equation
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1\\3&5&2&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{pmatrix}=0.
$$